# Side-by-side installation of Outlook 2007 and 2010

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, sync, microsoft-outlook-2010

According to Microsoft ([KB980513](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980513)), Windows Mobile Device Center can't sync with Outlook 2010 64-bit. I use Outlook as a POP client, no Exchange. My question is can I install Outlook 2007 (32-bit) without messing up the 2010 installation? Will they share the `.pst` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've read - I haven't tried it - you can have various Office versions installed side by side, but not Outlook. It's curious, but there must be something about Outlook where you cannot have multiple versions installed. If you need Outlook 2007, you should modify your Office 2010 installation to remove that Outlook, then install Outlook 2k7.

Comment: No, I don't "need" Outlook 2007 except to sync my phone. Too bad, I prefer the 2010 interface. I only sync about once a week anyway, so I guess I can learn to live without.

Comment: This answer explains why not: http://superuser.com/a/424806/27789

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not supported as such, you could run Outlook 2010 inside virtual machine. If you have Windows 7 best path would be to use [Windows XP mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx) for it.

Unfortunately there is no way you can share pst file between two installations of Outlook.

Comment: There are ways and means of sharing the PST file between different Outlook installations on different machines, and I've been doing it between two machines for almost a decade now - the easiest way is to use the file management screens to add it (via network share, etc.) and then change that to be the default mailbox. The only restriction is that you can only be in it from one PC at a time.

Comment: Original question was, in my opinion, related to two of them working at same time (one for mail, other for sync). I agree that two programs can access same files one-at-time without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not uninstall the x64 installation, and then install the x86 version instead? Then you'd get the improved user interface, and still be able to sync with your mobile device.